# how to select all tables with certain postfix in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I'm going to select all tables from a database that their names ends with "_language".
For example : "product_language" or "category_language" .
Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select all tables using information schema using bellow given query

```
SELECT 
    TABLE_NAME
from
    information_schema.TABLES
where
    TABLE_SCHEMA = 'Your_schema_name'
        and TABLE_NAME LIKE '%_language';
```

Answer (score 0):

[**Reference for MySQL SHOW command**](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mysql-show.php)

You can simnply go for SHOW command, like

```
SHOW tables like '%_language';
```

> Then it will display all the tables in MySQL DB with the table names that are ended by the name **'_language'**

```
mysql> SHOW TABLES LIKE '%_language';
```

**OUTPUT as**

```
+---------------------+
| Tables              |
+---------------------+
| product_language    |
| category_language   | 
+---------------------+
```

Comment: thanks . but it's not work correctly in Laravel framework. I use this : $tables = DB::select('SHOW tables like "%_language"');
        dd($tables);  and this returned : array(2) {
[0] object(stdClass)#730 (1) {
}
[1] object(stdClass)#729 (1) {
}